# Python sort 2D Array by using np.argosrt list entrys

Tags: python, numpy

I reshaped my given x,y data by np.reshape(x or y,(40,30)). Next I need to sort the y-Values by ascending order, so I used:

```
y_sort=np.argsort(y,axis=-1)
print y_sort
[[1 10 6 84 20 ..
          5 240 63 88...]]
```

Next I want to try to use this index list for sorting my "new" y-2D array with

```
y_new=y[y_sort]
```

Now I got for y_new a tuple of 40,30,30

I just want to sort the y-Values of my origin 2D array with respect to the given indices y_sort, resulting in a 2D Array of size 40,30

What am I doing wrong here?

Thanks for help

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `numpy`'s `arg*` functions should not be used as `index`. They only mention this in [numpy.argwhere](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/generated/numpy.argwhere.html) but I tested several of them and all of the tested `arg*` functions trigger advanced indexing (see [Numpy Documentation](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html#integer-array-indexing)).

Probably [`numpy.sort`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/generated/numpy.sort.html#numpy.sort) is the suitable function for sorting.